# formpanel.submit does not submit the file on GWT server

Tags: gwt, gwt2, formpanel

i want to send a file from client to server.

My code:

**Client side**:

```java
private FormPanel getFormPanel() {
    if (formPanel == null) {
        formPanel = new FormPanel();
    formPanel.setMethod(FormPanel.METHOD_POST);
        formPanel.setEncoding(FormPanel.ENCODING_MULTIPART);
        formPanel.setAction(GWT.getHostPageBaseURL() +"UploadFileServlet");
        formPanel.setWidget(getFlexTable_1());

                System.out.println(GWT.getHostPageBaseURL() +"UploadFileServlet");
    }
    return formPanel;
}
```

**In `getFlexTable_1()`**

```java
flexTable.setWidget(1, 1, getFileUpload());
```

**In `getFileUpload()`**

```java
private FileUpload getFileUpload() {
    if (fileUpload == null) {
        fileUpload = new FileUpload();
        fileUpload.setName("upload");
    }
    return fileUpload;
}

private Button getAddButton() {
        if (addButton == null) {
            addButton = new Button("ADD");
            addButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
                public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                               formPanel.submit();
        }
        });
    }
return addButton;
```

}

**On server side**

```java
public class CmisFileUpload extends HttpServlet implements Servlet{

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doPost(request, response);
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        byte[] buffer = new byte[115200];//
        String fileName = null;
        String mimetype = null;
        String majorVersion = null;
        InputStream stream = null;
        System.out.println("ServletWorking Fine");
}
```

**Now when i Choose a file and click on ADD button i cant see the output on server side for this code `System.out.println("ServletWorking Fine");`**

The outPut of `System.out.println(GWT.getHostPageBaseURL() +"UploadFileServlet");` on client side is

```java
http://127.0.0.1:8888/UploadFileServlet
```

and when i use this url directly on browser i get server side output for `System.out.println("ServletWorking Fine");`**

---

**Edited**

I created one more web application for file upload

```java
public class Uploadfile implements EntryPoint {

    FormPanel uploadForm = new FormPanel();
    public void onModuleLoad() {

        HorizontalPanel horizontalPanel = new HorizontalPanel();

      uploadForm.setAction(GWT.getHostPageBaseURL() +"UploadFileServlet"); 

        uploadForm.setEncoding(FormPanel.ENCODING_MULTIPART); 
        uploadForm.setMethod(FormPanel.METHOD_POST); 
        horizontalPanel.add(uploadForm);

        // Create a panel to hold all of the form widgets. 
        VerticalPanel panel = new VerticalPanel(); 
        uploadForm.setWidget(panel); 

        FlexTable flexTable = new FlexTable();
        panel.add(flexTable);

        // Create a FileUpload widget. 
        FileUpload upload = new FileUpload(); 
        upload.setName("uploadFormElement"); 
        flexTable.setWidget(2, 3, upload);
        // panel.add(upload); 

        // Add a 'submit' button. 
        Button uploadSubmitButton = new Button("Submit"); 
        panel.add(uploadSubmitButton); 

        uploadSubmitButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 uploadForm.submit(); 
            }
        });
        uploadForm.addFormHandler(new FormHandler() { 
          public void onSubmit(FormSubmitEvent event) { 
          } 
          public void onSubmitComplete(FormSubmitCompleteEvent event) { 
            Window.alert(event.getResults()); 
          } 
        }); 
        RootPanel.get().add(horizontalPanel); 
    }
}
```

**Server**

```java
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, 
            HttpServletResponse response) 
                            throws ServletException, IOException { 
      doPost(request, response);
  }

  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, 
            HttpServletResponse response) 
                            throws ServletException, IOException { 

      System.out.println("working fine" );
   }
```

This code is working fine

According to me there is no difference between the codes.

Plz tell me why the formpanel.submit is not working properly.

Plz help.

Comment: What are you seeing in your browser developer tools (Firebug or Chrome Dev Tools or equivalent in another browser), in the Network tab? Is it sending anything? the expected request? to which URL?

Comment: @ThomasBroyer  I am using Firebug. In networkTab the Url is 127.0.0.1:8888/UploadFileServlet and timeline is just working. Nothing else

Comment: @ThomasBroyer   In networkTab the Url is 127.0.0.1:8888/UploadFileServlet and timeline is just working. Nothing else

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is `hide()` method is closing the window??? If Yes then

remove move code `hide();` after `formPanel.submit();`

for `hide()` use `FormHandler`. for eg

```java
uploadForm.addFormHandler(new FormHandler() {

    public void onSubmitComplete(FormSubmitCompleteEvent event) {
        hide();
    }

    public void onSubmit(FormSubmitEvent event) {

    }

});
```

reason: The `FormPanel` must not be detached (i.e. removed from its parent until the submission is complete. Otherwise, notification of submission will fail.

Comment: this works.. this is widget is a dialogbox which is hidden after submit class..
thanks for explaination.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Why you have mapped for GET method for file upload. The GET request method is serving for the url entered in browser. Remove the GET Request Map, it will work.

For the POST request map, you can use MultipartFile for RequestParam as below

```
protected void uploadFileAndReconcilePayout1(@RequestParam("documentUpload") MultipartFile file, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        //code for file working

    }
```

Comment: yes I underStand.Any way doGET method is calling doPost method.
There is no problem on the serverSide. There is something wrong with the formPanel.I can say this because the same code is working in another webApplication.